# using images for tabs in sencha touch

Tags: css, extjs

I am using sencha touch tab controls. I am trying to override the default tab css with an image, but it doesn't seem to work. Can any one provide me with a sample.

Answer (score 0):

You can change it by defineing a icon in your .html file. And use that defined class in your tabPanel using `iconCls`.

Answer (score 0):

for example in your .html file

```
.image{
-webkit-mask-box-image: url('/public/images/btn.png');
}
```

and use the above defined image in your tabPanel

```
iconCls: 'image',
```